# How to remove false error of Item not present in enum in json schema

Tags: java, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to validate json using json Schema for which I am using oneOf , it is able to catch the issue but it is giving one false error "Value "Test12" is not defined in enum." along with the actual error "Integer -5 is less than minimum value of 0." Is it any way possible to avoid the first error ? When it is passing then I am not getting any errors. I am using this website to validate - https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

```
"$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "eventName": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": ["Test10", "Test12", "Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]
    },
    "eventPayload": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "totalAmount": {
                "type": "number"
            }
        }
    }
},
"oneOf": [
    {
        "properties": {
            "eventName": {
                "enum": ["Test10", "Test12"]
            },
            "eventPayload": {
                "properties": {
                    "totalAmount": {
                        "exclusiveMinimum": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "properties": {
            "eventName": {
                "enum": ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]
            },
            "eventPayload": {
                "properties": {
                    "totalAmount": {
                        "exclusiveMaximum": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

json

```
   {
       {
"eventName": "Test12",
"eventPayload": {
  "totalAmount": -5
     }
}
```

Errors

```
Message:
Value "Test12" is not defined in enum.
Schema path:
#/oneOf/1/properties/eventName/enum
Message:
Integer -5 is less than minimum value of 0.
Schema path:
#/oneOf/0/properties/eventPayload/properties/totalAmount/minimum
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's incorrect to report this. The schema specifies a `oneOf` with two subschemas.  The error messages indicate why each subschema fails.

- `Test12` isn't a member of the second subschema `enum`, so failure
- -5 < 0 for both subschemas, so failure

If anything, I'd also expect the error about the -5 to be reported for the second subschema, giving a total of 3 errors.

Comment: @gregsdennnis But it is not a check.. it should be like if this enum contains Test12 then perform below check else move to different item of array.

Comment: Also if we can control that if a particulae oneof fails then dont throw error

Comment: @Loren But putting the focus on "just" checking the eventName enum and ignoring any additional definitions (and therefore maybe skipping to report validation errors) is a meaning you are adding to the schema and the content. The validator checks all definitions and reports everything with the same priority.

Comment: Also, the error message you get is highly dependent on the validator you are using. From the python package `jsonschema`, you would just get: `ValidationError: {'eventName': 'Test12', 'eventPayload': {'totalAmount': -5}} is not valid under any of the given schemas`

Comment: @DanielSchneider I am using   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.networknt</groupId>
   <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.49</version>
  </dependency>